# Best room database for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive, flutter-floor

I am about to start a flutter project and coming from android kotlin I was looking for the closest database to room.
I have read about floor and hive.
Before spending hours using both to figure out which one to stick to, I was wondering what you suggest guys.
I don't want to use firebase since the data remain mainly on tve user's device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor). It is closest to room.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with room and Kotlin I'd say Floor is your best bet for Flutter. While I haven't used either, I have used other object mappers with SQLite as well as Hive.

Now Hive as non-SQL database is totally different from an SQL based database.